# Traverse List recursively of java class

Tags: java, list

I have one class release it contain list object of its self now i want that recursive list to get parsed and want it in one list.

Here is my class :

```
public class OnTimeNowRelease implements Serializable
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int id;
    String name;
    String can_modify;
    String start_date;
    String due_date;
    String velocity_start_date;
    String release_notes;
    String status;
    String is_active;
    String release_type;
    List<OnTimeNowRelease> children ; 
    getter setter//
}
```

How can I traverse `List` of children up to nth level? its like traversing tree..if object does not have child its value is `children = null`

Comment: `Now i can traverse List of children upto nth level`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple Traversal example, which you mostly see in LinkedList or Trees.

```
public void fetchAllChildren(OnTimeNowRelease root, List<OnTimeNowRelease> childList){
    // if the parent is not defined, nothing to do
    if(root == null){
         return;
    }

    //add the parent to the list. Since java is Reference by Value, the list can be used for recursively adding all the descending elements 
    childList.add(root);
    if(root.children !=null && !root.children.isEmpty()){   
         for(OnTimeNowRelease children : root.children){
                //simple recursive solution add all the children and their children and so on....
                fetchAllChildren(root.children, childList);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
public List<OnTimeNowRelease> flattenLists(OnTimeNowRelease obj) {
    List<OnTimeNowRelease> result = new ArrayList<OnTimeNowRelease>();
    List<OnTimeNowRelease> children = obj.getChildren(); 
    if (children==null || children.isEmpty()) {
        return result;
    } else {
        for (OnTimeNowRelease child : children) {
            result.addAll(flattenLists(child));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This will iterate over all the children of each `List` and recursively add each of their child elements to one big list. You only have to initially call it with the root element once.

Answer (score -1):

I don not know what yo want exactly: put in list all items in the tree to print it? move the childs of one item to his parent?

In the first case you can add a recoursive function to the class who obtain it:

```
public List<OnTimeNowRelease> obtainDescendants() {
    // create a list for the childs
    List<OnTimeNowRelease> items = new ArrayList<OnTimeNowRelease>();
    // add myself
    items.addAll(this);

    if(children != null) {
        // add my childs and his childs to the list
        for(OnTimeNowRelease child : this.children) {       
            items.addAll( child.obtainDescendants() );
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

In the seconds case you can do something like

```
public void inherintChilds() {  
    if( children == null) {
        return;
    }    

    for(OnTimeNowRelease child : this.children) {
         if( child.children != null) {      
             // take the childs
             this.children.addAll(child.children);
             // quit to my child
             child.children = null;                        
         }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code. It would be much more helpful when you would explain how your code works and why it works.